# Show specific column from pool_nodes

Tags: postgresql, nodes, pool, pgpool

i'm running show pool_nodes and it's work. What if i want to return just the 4th column(status), using only query. It is possible ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pgpool-admin extension, then you can use SQL queries.

```
SELECT status FROM pcp_node_info()
```

Here is the documentation reference:
https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/pgpool-adm.html